# Avoid getting old data from customerRegistry in queue runner

Tags: magento2.3.4, message-queue, repositories

We have a Magento 2 Queue Job which loads a customer

```
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository */
$this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerId));
```

Now we noticed, that on subsequent processing of queue messages for the same customer, always old data is returned.

We first thought we have a race condition and process events to quickly (before being persisted to the database), but later saw, that if we kill the queue runners in between, the right data is returned.

Digging deeper we see that the customer repository is caching in the customer registry

```
public function getById($customerId)
{
    $customerModel = $this->customerRegistry->retrieve($customerId);
    return $customerModel->getDataModel();
}
```

And the registry is just caching data in a the instance:

```
public function retrieve($customerId)
{
    if (isset($this->customerRegistryById[$customerId])) {
        return $this->customerRegistryById[$customerId];
```

So now the queue job runs a long time and will have eventually old data.

How can this be solved in a clean way?

Can we force somehow to get fresh data from the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Calling remove on the registry seems to work, but I am wondering if there is a nicer solution, because eventually any nested addresses might still be cached.

```
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry */
    $this->customerRegistry->remove($this->customerId);
    $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerId));
```

*Edit*

We come to the conclusion that it might not be good to do heavy lifting & loading of entities in a queue.

In our case we use the queue because we communicate with an external system. I seams a better and more reasonable pattern to generate the full payload for before queuing and only do the REST call itself withing the queue runner.

Comment: It looks like `remove` is only available in the `CustomerRegistry`, not in for example the order registry. That one only has a `delete` method which seems to delete the object.

Comment: Exactly, it's a big mess. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using OrderRepositoryInterface and trying to load order there. OrderRepository is keeping loaded models in its registry. Only solution I found is to create fresh version of OrderRepository using factory.

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterfaceFactory;
...
/** @var OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository */
$orderRepository = $this->factory->create();
$order = $orderRepository->get($entityId);
```